# How can I iterate through a websites search results and gather meta-data?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an assignment that requires me to iterate through a website's search results, which are links to journals, to gather each journal's link and other meta-data (authors, date, etc...) and output them to a .txt file using at least Java and Apache HTTPClient, but no web crawlers.  Here is the website: https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/reviews/topics .  I am to choose any of the categories shown and gather the aforementioned data for each of the journal links in that category.

Below is a bit of code I found online to gather the HTTP entity and response body via Apache HTTPClient.  The program I am facing is when using a simple URL like google.com, it works fine and displays the page's source code for me to later parse.  However, the page I need to use is full of JavaScript wizardry and is not cooperating. Each search result page ends with the "/search" end-point.  Through my browser's web developer tools, I managed to find a direct link to
the current result page I am viewing:

https://www.cochranelibrary.com/en/search?p_p_id=scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_displayText=Allergy+%26+intolerance&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_searchText=Allergy+%26+intolerance&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_searchType=basic&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_facetQueryField=topic_id&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_searchBy=13&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_facetDisplayName=Allergy+%26+intolerance&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_facetQueryTerm=z1506030924307755598196034641807&_scolarissearchresultsportlet_WAR_scolarissearchresults_facetCategory=Topics

However, when attemping to use this it returns a 419 error, which is apparently some unauthorized access/token issue.  So at this point, that is my main problem, I just cannot "import" a categories' search results to even attempt iterating through to gather the required data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  String url = "http://www.google.com";
  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

  try
  {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    httpget.addHeader("User-Agent",USER_AGENT);

    System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>()
    {
      public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response) throws IOException
      {
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status >= 200 && status < 300)
        {
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
        }
        else
        { throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status); }
      }
    };

    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(responseBody);

  }
  finally
  { httpclient.close(); }
}
```

**UPDATE**
So I consolidated the code quite a bit after looking at the Apache HTTPClient docs, just to make it easier to work and test with:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException
    {
      // Builds the URI
      URI uri = new URIBuilder()
          .setScheme("https")
          .setHost("www.cochranelibrary.com")
          .setPath("/")
          .build();

      // Uses Fluent API to execute GET request with uri
      try
      { System.out.println(Request.Get(uri).execute().returnContent().asString()); }
      catch (IOException e)
      { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

However, this particular domain continues to give me issues.  Just attempting to GET from www.cochranelibrary.com returns a 419 error.  I thought maybe it was something with the HTTPS protocol, but testing on https://www.httpvshttps.com returns perfectly fine.  I'm lost as to why this particular domain is being stubborn.